# What is the difference of current and voltage in electronic devices?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Electronic devices are generally described as "operating from this voltage range". Why is the voltage range at which electronic devices always given? Isn't the amount of current important? For example, if we give 100 thousand volts to a 9V device, but the current is extreme low, what happens?

Comment: Depends on the device, and the method of applying the voltage.

Comment: Actually, I need to ask: Can an electronic device use a statement that says, "It works with this amount of current" instead of "It works in this voltage range"?

Comment: Fuses don't care about the voltage, only about the current (assuming it doesn't flash over).

Comment: Think of voltage as pressure. And think of current as water flow. Sure, the water flow is what is important. But when you want to attach a pump, you need to know if the system can sustain the pump's pressure.

Comment: @Steeven Hmm.. an interesting and logical example. :D

Comment: @Steeven, the water flow is important if you're trying to fill a bucket, but the water-as-electricity analogy works best if we imagine the pipe to make a complete circuit, with the water returning to the pump over and over again. If you have a water-powered device in the circuit, the amount of power that it consumes will be proportional to the product of the flow rate and the pressure drop--exactly like how a device in an electric circuit consumes power proportional to the product of the current and the voltage drop.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Well then, let's imagine a water system where the water flow pulls a turbine. Then we have a closed water system and our water analogy is more accurate

Answer (score 2):

Most things (electronic devices, electronic components, bowls of salt water, cats, etc.) have a fairly fixed current/voltage relationship.  Some also have a time component to that relationship.

If I grab onto the terminals of a 5 volt supply that's capable of supplying 100 amps, 100 amps will not go through my body -- depending on whether I'm sweaty and how much surface area I present to the terminals, somewhere around $10\mu\mathrm{A}$ will flow.

So you can't apply "100 thousand volts but with extremely low" current to any random object -- a 1 meter square pane of glass, with $100\mathrm{kV}$ applied to opposite edges will conduct almost no current.  $100\mathrm{kV}$ from a source that can supply large currents applied to a bowl of salt water will result in a spectacular steam explosion.

$100\mathrm{kV}$ from a source that's current limited (that's the closest we can get to your $100\mathrm{kV}$ at low current in the real world), applied to a "9V" device would be interesting -- because in theory-land, the source would just current limit, and the "9V" device would pull the voltage down to whatever it is at the current flowing.  In reality if you did the experiment you'd almost certainly inadvertently make a capacitor that would be charged up to $100\mathrm{kV}$.  At the instant that you connected the leads of that 9V device, the voltage on the 9V device would depend on the capacitance of your source and of the device -- so you might blow up the thing in the initial surge, or maybe it would pull the voltage low enough soon enough that it would settle out to working the way that naive theory says it would.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A satisfactory answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Tim did a good answer as to what happens when you overdrive a device.  As for why we talk about the voltages a device operates on, there's pragmatic reasons for this.  A lot of our major sources of power work on voltages.  Generators provide a constant voltage.  Batteries provide near constant voltage in the region we care about.

Voltage limited systems also tend to require less wiring.  We can wire them in parallel and every single device gets exactly the same voltage.  The wiring for this in the walls is trivial.  If your devices were defined by current limits, you'd need to give individual legs to each device, or else all devices would have to agree on a level of current to draw.  As it turns out, it's *much* easier to get everyone to agree on, say, 120V, than it is to have your toothbrush charger pull the same amperage as your air conditioning!

In the lower voltage DC world, we do see more current based thinking.  In those worlds the voltages are so fixed (5V and 12V) that nobody even thinks of doing anything else.  There you will see devices rated for current draw.  For example, large graphics cards are required to draw their own power directly from the power supply, while smaller cards are permitted to pull power from the PICe bus you plug it into.  This is because the larger cards are too power hungry, and demand more than the PCIe bus was ready to support!

Comment: Re, "Generators provide a constant voltage." That is true if you drive the generator shaft at a constant speed. Electric power stations and portable generator sets are _intentionally designed_ to do just that because of the advantages of constant voltage that you described above.

Comment: "... If your devices were defined by current limits ..." Interestingly, there's a sort-of precedent for this: starting (I think!) in the 1940's and continuing on through the end of the vacuum tube era, low-power vacuum tube equipment was designed with tube heaters hooked up in series, to save needing a heater transformer.  Tube lineups were designed so that every tube pulled the same current, with higher-power tubes needing more heater voltage.  (Search on All American Five and All American Seven for example tube lineups).

Answer (score 0):

For a lot of devices the applied voltage $V$ will determine the current $I$ through the device and hence the power dissipated $VI$ within the device.  If that power is dissipated as hear and it is above the design value then the temperature of the device may be so high that the device is destroyed.

Most power supplies are voltage sources and they maintain a constant voltage output irrespective of the current drawn from the supply.
This means that it is the working voltage which is quoted.
For example a $24\,\rm V$ light bulb will work satisfactorily with a $24\,\rm V$ power supply but with a $240\,\rm V$ power supply the current and hence power dissipated will be too high and the light bulb will blow.

For capacitors the situation is slightly different.
A capacitor consists of two conducting plates with a material which is an insulator between them.
If the voltage applied to the plates is too high the insulator will “break down” and become a conductor resulting in a current passing through the “insulator” and a heating effect which will destroy the capacitor.